# CodeIgniter CSRF 403 error

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I'm trying to solve this problem for a long time and stil have no clue to it.
I am trying to send and catch AJAX request within CodeIgniter framework. 
PHP file with page tamplate:

```
<table id="jivoClients" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($clients as $client): ?>
            <td class="details-control" id="<?php echo $client["chat_id"]. ","
                        .$this->security->get_csrf_token_name(). ","
                        .$this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>"></td>
            <th class="clientData"><?php echo str_replace(",", "<br>" , $client["visitor_info"]); ?></th>
            <th class="clientData"><?php echo ($client['session_geoip_country']); ?></th>
            <th class="clientData"><?php echo ($client['session_geoip_city']); ?></th>
            <th class="clientData"><?php echo ($client['visitor_chats_count']); ?></th>
            <th class="clientData"><?php echo ($client['agents_names']); ?></th>
            <th class="clientData"><?php if(isset($client['messages']['0']['timestamp'])): ?>
                <?php echo date('m/d/Y', $client['messages']['0']['timestamp']); ?>
                <?php endif;?></th>
            <th class="clientData"><?php if(isset($client['messages']['0']['timestamp'])): ?>
                <?php echo date('H:i:s', $client['messages']['0']['timestamp']); ?>
                <?php endif;?></th>
            <th class="clientData"><?php if(isset($client['messages']['0']['Message'])): ?>
                <?php echo ($client['messages']['0']['Message']); ?>
                <?php endif;?></th>
            <th class="clientData"><?php echo ($client['Manager_note']); ?></th>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In my js file code looks like:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var messageData = id.split(",");
    var token = "" + messageData[1];
    var post_data = {
        'id' : messageData[0],
        'csrf_crm' : messageData[2]
    }
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data: {
            func : 'getNewLocations',
            'id' : messageData[0],
            'csrf_crm' : messageData[2]
        },
        url:'application/controllers/AjaxController.php',

        success: function(result, statut) {
            if (result == 'add') {
                //do something
            }
            else if (result == 'remove') {
                //do something
            }
        }
    });
```

And I constantly get 403 error. As I already read on forum, it means that my CSRF token is not correct. But it seems that I get it normally (checked in debugger).
However this does not solve the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the config file set $config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE; to $config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;

Comment: Make sure your have make csrf token regeneration false in your config file otherwise it will re generate a new token in each request. $config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;

Comment: Done that. No result

Comment: Are you sending token with correct name ? The token name should be match with $config['csrf_token_name'] defined in config.php file

Comment: Yes. Tripple checked.

Comment: `url:'application/controllers/AjaxController.php',` can you ensure that this path is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem.
It appered, that I was using incorrect route in js file.
The correct sequence of actions looks like this:
1) add new line in file routes.php:

```
$route['jivosite/user'] = 'jivosite/user';
```

2) add code in js file:
post_data = JSON.stringify(post_data);

```
    post_data = JSON.stringify(post_data);
    var url = baseurl + "jivosite/user"
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhr.response);
        }
    });
    xhr.addEventListener("error", function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    xhr.send(post_data ? JSON.stringify(post_data) : null);
```

3) check config.php file. 
`$config['cookie_secure']   = FALSE;` should be like this
and `$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('jivosite/user');` should include my route

4) create file Jivosite.php in controllers folder with contents:

```
class Jivosite extends CI_Controller
{
    public function user()
    {
        $id=$this->input->post('id');
        echo $id;
    }
}
```

And it worked for me.
Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `echo` to assign value of php variable. Also wrap token in `''`

```
var token = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash() ?>'; //<----- do echo here
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data: {
                    func : 'getNewLocations',
                    'id' : id,
                    'csrf_crm' : token
                },
                url:'application/controllers/AjaxController.php',

                success: function(result, statut) {
                    if (result == 'add') {
                        //do something
                    }
                    else if (result == 'remove') {
                        //do something
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for correction, but it does not solve main problem - toen is not accepted by CodeIgniter

Comment: change `csrf_crm` to `<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(), ?>` then try. Also I have doubt in `func : `

Comment: Can't insert php code into js file. So I copied name from config file and inserted it into data array. As for function, don't pay much attention to it for now, because it does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Get the csrf token value like this:

```
var token = $('[name="csrf_token"]').val();
```

Comment: Thanks. Interresting way to get token name. But it seems to me this is not the problem, because token is not sent correctly.

Comment: There are 2 other things you can apply and cross check 1. the url (try appending baseurl too), 2. change 'csrf_crm' to 'csrf_token'

Comment: 1) Changed 'csrf_crm' to 'csrf_token' - no result

Comment: 2) POST http://crmtzpua/application/controllers/AjaxController.php 403 (Forbidden) indicates that base url is appended normally.

Comment: So, I think it is not the problem. Thank for ideas.

Comment: Don't think this is the issue but noticed that you have success: function(result, statut) { instead of success: function(result, status) { ... maybe typo error.